# Aggregate Combine Two ObjectAarrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to combine the user of a comment with a profilepicture in NodeJS so the profilepicture is shown, when the comment appears.

I have following code:

```
 Mission.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: ({ $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)] })
            }
        },
        {
            $limit: 1
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                "path": "$comments",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                "from": "users",
                "localField": "comments.user",
                "foreignField": "username",
                "as": "user"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                "path": "$user",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "comment": { "$push": "$comments" },
                "user": { "$push": "$user.profilePicture" },
            }
        }
     ], ...)
```

The mission model looks like this:

```
creator: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 100
    },
comments: [{
        user: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minLength: 2,
            maxLength: 500
        },
        date: {
            date: Date
        }
    }]
```

and the user model looks like this:

```
 username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            index: { unique: true },
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 16
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            minlength: 60,
            maxlength: 60
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            validate: {
                validator: function (v) {
                    return /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/.test(v);
                },
                message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email address!'
            },
        },
        profilePicture: {
            type: String
        },
        creationDate: {
            type: Date,
        },
        api: {
            apiKey: {
                type: String
            },
            apiSecret: {
                type: String
            }
        }
```

The question is: How can I get the comment and the profilePicture in the same object?

Comment: Can't really tell you without data to reproduce from as showing the code you have is only part of the story. In order for people to clearly see what you are doing and want to achieve you need to show  a small selection of source documents and ideally the desired result that can be obtained from that sample. The code is there as a guide to show what you have attempted and how you have approached doing it and it's likely an answer will not just be one small change to your code anyway.

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the question with the models

Comment: You were not being asked for Models or JSONSchema. You were being asked for "data" that is actually present within the stored documents. Read the comment again because it's pretty clear in what it tells you to do. Perhaps get someone to translate if english is not your first language.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write (May this will work for you)

```
     {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "userInfo":{
              $push: {
               "comment": "$comments",
               "user": "$user.profilePicture"
             }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: sounds good, but unfortunatly doesn't work, I updated the question with more data